# Is it safe to film during airplane take off and landing?

Tags: air-travel, safety, aircraft, photography

Recently I saw may youtuber reviewing flight experience and the common shot I saw is the take off and landing.

My question is,

1. Is it **safe** to use electronic device to film the take off and landing ? (I assumed most youtuber is using Gopro kind of camera)
2. Is it **allowed** to use electronic device to film the take off and landing ?

I have been researching and the answer is quite broad. and mostly they are talking about a snapping photo, not a clip video. but still, conclusion is passenger should keep everything in the front pocket or under the seat during take off and landing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use a camera during take off and landing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51203/can-you-use-a-camera-during-take-off-and-landing)

Comment: on 2 - if the airline says it's not allowed, it's not allowed. Airplanes are not public spaces, so the airline rules apply

Comment: It's safe. Most airlines either allow or ignore it. It happens all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Listen to the safety briefing and other announcements. The airline will tell you what you shouldn't do.

My experience: They used to tell passengers to switch off all electronic devices, but starting from a few years ago, they started telling passengers to switch off *large* electronic devices, and small devices may be used if they are securely held in your hand.

And in all cases, devices that have a flight mode should be switched to flight mode, even if turned off (so that they'll be in flight mode when you turn them back on during the flight).

Comment: Is the flight mode part of your answer referring to the safety or rules part of the question? Surely flight mode isn't needed in all cases, for example when connecting to the plane's complimentary wifi.

Comment: @JJJ Just to confuse things a bit, at least on iOS 15.0 on Apple devices, Airplane Mode disables [neither Bluetooth or WiFi](https://i.imgur.com/psCa6Ho.png), only cellular communications. I recall earlier it turned those off but you could re-enable them and stay in Airplane Mode.

Comment: @JJJ with android (and ios apparently from the above comment) you should enable flight mode and enable the wifi if you want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases.  Years ago the airlines and regulators determined that electronic devices are safe to use in all phases of flight.

There are 1000's of videos of takeoff and landing on Rumble, Odysee, YouTube, etc.

The Cabin Crew will announce the specific rules so listen carefully.

Large electronic devices must be stowed because they become a significant projectile risk in an emergency situation.